# What was IBM's internal Specification Language of the 1980s?

Tags: history

Within IBM's internal Development community, there was a move in the 1980s to bring our skills up to date. As part of this, we were introduced to a specification language, independent of the programming languages of the time (PL/S and Basic Assembler for example), in which a specification would be implemented. This specification language, as I recall, embodied set theory and logic in a type-safe context.

In fact, in the IBM Hursley Lab we eventually chose to use the Z notation from the Programming Research Group at Oxford University. This was perhaps more strictly mathematical than the IBM language - part of a Formal Methods approach.

However, I spent quite a bit of time with the IBM specification language and I would very much like to know if anyone recalls what it was called and what happened to it.
It had a “specification checker” for type consistency etc and I remember it very fondly, before getting immersed in the Z notation.

Comment: I'm thinking it was the "Vienna Definition Language"? https://foldoc.org/Vienna+Definition+Language - see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Development_Method#History

Comment: See if this article rings a bell - https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/356596.356598 (PDF is freely available here)

Comment: Thanks @davidbak I’m not thinking of VDM which, like Z, is more mathematically formal than the IBM language I am searching for.